# Confusion regarding getchar() in c

Tags: c, binary

I was reading a book and this part confuses me a bit regarding `getchar()`

```
int peekchar(void){

        int c;
        c = getchar();
        if(c!=EOF) ungetc(c,stdin);
        return c;

}

int readNumber(void){

        int accumulator=0;     /*Number read so far*/
        int c;

     while((c = peekchar()) != EOF && isdigit(c)) {
     c = getchar();             /* consume it */
     accumulator *= 10;         /* shift previous digits over */
     accumulator += (c - '0');  /* add decimal value of new digit */
   }
return accumulator;
}
```

What exactly happens here in `accumulator += (c - '0');`

And the input would be `digits` i.e `123` would be given as input and that will be printed as output `123` again. This is what the program does. Any explanation would be helpful guys.

Comment: c and c++ are distinct languages. If your question is about c, it's not helpful to tag c++.

Comment: sorry about that man :)

Comment: `c - '0'` will return the difference between the value of the character stored by `c` and the value of the character '`0`'. Since numerals have incremental values, (each numeral's character's value is 1 larger than the previous), that offset is equivalent to the value that character represents. For example, (`'4' - '0' == 4`).